# Packing $1$cm$\times 2$cm$\times 4$cm bars of chocolate into boxes of size $8$cm$\times12$cm$\times 12$cm and $8$cm$\times 5$cm$\times 5$cm

Tags: geometry

The question is as follows:

> A company markets a rectangular chocolate bar that measures $1$cm by $2$cm by $4$cm. How many of these bars can be packed in a rectangular box that measures $8$cm by $12$cm by $12$cm? How many of these bars can be packed in rectangular box that measures $8$cm by $5$cm by $5$cm? How would you pack them?

I found the volume of the $1$cm by $2$cm by $4$cm box, and got it to be $8\text{cm}^3$. I took the volume of the $8$cm by $12$cm by $12$cm box and divided it by $8\text{cm}^3$, which I got to be **144 bars**. I did the same thing for the $8$cm by $5$cm by $5$cm box (volume: $200\text{cm}^3$), and divided it by $8\text{cm}^3$, to get **25 bars**.

I am stumped with the part of the question that says how I would pack them. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure in each case that you can pack them so there is no empty space? That is pretty obvious for the first box, but not for the second. To decide, you'll have to figure out how to pack them. Try drawing pictures; there's really no other reasonable way.

Answer (score 5):

Packing the $8 \times 12 \times 12$ box is easy.  You can cut $8 \times 12$ into $12\ 2 \times 4$ rectangles and make $12$ layers like that because the dimensions of the bar divide evenly into the dimensions of the box.  You can't pack $25$ bars into the $8 \times 5 \times 5$ box.  Each $ 5 \times 5$layer contains $2,4,$ or $8$ cm$^3$ of the bars that form part of it, so the total volume of the layer occupied by bars must be even and cannot exceed $24$ cm$^3$.  You therefore cannot put more than $24$ bars into the box.

To show you can get $24$, show how to pack $12$ dominoes into the $5 \times 5$ square at the end.  Let each domino represent the cross section of a bar and stack the bars two high to make a height of $8$.  To pack $12$ dominoes, make two stacks of $5$ horizontal ones and one stack of two vertical ones.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd understand it like this:
As the chocolate bars can not be arbitrarily divided, you have to pack them in such a way, that they add up to the entire volume of the box. For the first box, this is simple, because you can divide 8, 12 and 12 by 1, 2 and 4.
For the second box, this requires a bit of puzzling

Best regards :)